# Get all extreme points of Linear Program in CPLEX

Tags: java, linear-programming, cplex, basis

I need to enumerate all basis corresponding to all extreme points of a LP with the CPLEX API in Java. Unfortunately I did not find any way to do this with CPLEX. Is there a solution ?

If not, I will do this myself but I will need to play with basis. Is any simple way with CPLEX to enumerate all basis and check if a basis is a feasible solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: no.

There is no easy way to do this. One possible approach, but somewhat cumbersome, is to encode the basis using binary variables. E.g.:

```
xb[i] = 1 for basic variables 
        0 for non-basic variables
```

We need to add constraints on non-basic variables: they will be at bound. I.e. for a non-negative variable `x[i]` we have

```
xb[i]=0 => x[i]=0
```

(this is an indicator constraint). Furthermore we know that

```
sum(i,xb[i]) = m
```

(the number of basic variables is equal to the number of rows in the model).

Then use Cplex's **solution pool** to enumerate all possible feasible bases. An illustration for this approach is shown in this [link](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/01/finding-all-optimal-lp-solutions-using.html). (This particular example enumerates all optimal bases, but it is not difficult to tell Cplex to enumerate all feasible bases).